# optaplanner rule does not properly solve

Tags: drools, drools-planner, optaplanner

I made an optaplanner rule (see below).

```
//in expressway long tunnel(over 1km), equipment interval(400m)

rule "lcs_transport_tunnel_expway"

when
  $road : RoadVO(roadCtgry=="EXPWAY")
  $t1 : Transport(transportCode=="TUNNEL", $direction:direction,
                    Math.abs(mileageBegin-mileageEnd)>1000, 
                    $mileageBegin:mileageBegin, $mileageEnd:mileageEnd )
  $e0 : ItsEquipment(itsClass=="LCS", direction==$direction,
                    mileage >$mileageBegin && <$mileageEnd, $id:id, $mileage:mileage)
  $e1 : ItsEquipment(itsClass== "LCS", direction==$direction, id==$id+1,
                      mileage==$mileage+400 )
then
  scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1000);
end
```

While optaplanner is solving, `$e1 is not properly chosen.`
What is the problem?

Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Please indicate in your question what your desired result should be

Comment: My intention is arranging ItsEquipments with 400m intervals and same direction inside long tunnel. what is proper Drools expression? I'm newer to drools. please let me know sample code.

Answer (score 0):

(without knowing what the desired result is, it's hard to answer this, but here goes... :)

The 2 selected `ItsEquipment`'s don't constraint that they belong to the original selected `Transport` (or even the same `Transport`). They only need to belong to the same `direction`. Is that your intent?

The `$e1` selection has `id==$id+1` and `mileage==$mileage+400`. If your id's are unique, any other condition besides `id==$id+1` is pointless (including `mileage==$mileage+400`).

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey. But i'm newer to drools. please let me know some sample code.

Comment: If you want a POC, you might want to implement it in Java first, by extending `SimpleScoreCalculator`. Once that works - and it's clear to you what your goal is - then write it as DRL to get faster.